# Kali Linux (Kernel 4.19) MT7610u failed to load

Tags: networking, kali-linux, firmware, interface

I have installed Kali Linux alongside windows 10 on my system all is good except I get the following errors in `dmesg` every time I boot.

> mt76x0 1-1.3:1.0: firmware: failed to load mediatek/mt7610u.bin (-2)
>   mt76x0 1-1.3:1.0: Direct firmware load for mediatek/mt7610u.bin failed with error -2

My device is listed among the rest when I enter `lsusb`.

I have managed to get it to 'work' but it requires me to boot into windows 10 and then restart my PC. However, my internet connection is extremely slow and if my PC sleeps or is turned off I have to reboot windows then restart again.

Comment: Sounds like your NIC is failing. You might need to replace that.

Answer (score 1):

**MediaTek MT7610U** is a wi-fi integrated chip.
Errors in `dmesg` tell us it requires a proprietary firmware.

Usually vendors put them into the linux kernel. **NB:** they do not reside in the *common* kernel branch, instead they are in the linux-firmware branch[1] (I think for a licences reason...);
this means that you need an *extra* package in your system!

Once you have it, a reboot (it's the simplest way) will fix your issue.

---

Sorry if I have used wrong terms. Feel free to correct them!

[1] http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git;a=summary